# Is there a build command for meson?

Tags: c++, meson-build

Well I can init and **build** a meson with project as:

```sh
$ cd /tmp/
$ mkdir foobar; cd foobar
$ meson init --name foobar -l cpp --build
Using "foobar" (project name) as name of executable to build.
Sample project created. To build it run the
following commands:

meson builddir
ninja -C builddir

Building...
The Meson build system
Version: 0.53.2
Source dir: /tmp/foobar
Build dir: /tmp/foobar/build
Build type: native build
Project name: foobar
Project version: 0.1
C++ compiler for the host machine: c++ (gcc 9.3.0 "c++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0")
C++ linker for the host machine: c++ ld.bfd 2.34
Host machine cpu family: x86_64
Host machine cpu: x86_64
Build targets in project: 1

Found ninja-1.10.0 at /usr/bin/ninja
ninja: Entering directory `build'                                                                   
[2/2] Linking target foobar.
```

But with a created project, I have reading the man page and the website but I can find a command such as `$ meson build`.

Yes I know there is:

```sh
$ cd build
$ ninja
```

But I think that there is `--build` in `init` command...is it other for build?

Comment: meson compile would do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have configured your build you can do something like:

```
cd build
meson compile
```

or

```
meson compile -C build
```

See the docs @: https://mesonbuild.com/Running-Meson.html#building-from-the-source

Comment: Thanks. In spanish we say "if it is a tiger, maybe it eats me" because it is in the help `meson --help | grep compile` but in the man page it is not.

Comment: I like meson a lot, the docs are generally good. meson -h does display compile in the "commands" section. At least with version: `meson --version`  0.60.2

Comment: meson also protects you from doing "stupid" things like enforced split of the source and build trees. So don't be afraid for the tiger ;-).